# UISearchBar disappears when I tap second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have app with UIViewController which contains UISegmentView, UISearchDisplayController and UITableView like at picture:

[image]

When I tap into search bar, everything is fine. Keyboard appears and I can do my search activity. But after I tap into search bar second time, It disappears - on second picture:

[image]

When I add:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20,     self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height);
}
```

I can see search bar under searchResultsTableView:

[image]

Could anybody help me? Thank you!

Comment: this might be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989587/ios-7-uisearchdisplaycontroller-search-bar-disappears

Comment: Nope, it isn't. But thanks for try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally have the solution, but simultaneously I know that it isn't the best solution.

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    CGRect newFrame = [self.view.superview convertRect:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.superview.superview.frame toView:nil];
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.superview.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, -40, self.tableView.frame.size.width, window.bounds.size.height - newFrame.origin.y);
    return YES;
}
```

and

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    CGRect newFrame = [self.view.superview convertRect:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.superview.superview.frame toView:nil];
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.superview.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 4, self.tableView.frame.size.width, window.bounds.size.height - newFrame.origin.y);

    return YES;
}
```

and finally for content size:

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didHideSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}



- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void) keyboardWillHide {
    UITableView *tableView = [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView];

    [tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    [tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```